# Public record or PII

Tags: united-states, privacy

In the past, I had interactions via email with various boards of my town government. I recently noticed that printouts of these emails were scanned and added to the "meeting package" - a PDF document that is available on the town's website. The printout contains my name, email address, and in some instances my address and home phone number. Google OCR'd the PDF documents and finds them when I search for my email address.
(e.g. https://www.town.medfield.net/DocumentCenter/View/2309/BOS-Meeting-Packet-January-29-2019-PDF)

I asked for these documents to be redacted or removed, but I did not get a response and I don't expect any action. Is there a legal basis for this request, or can the town take the position that the correspondence is public record in its entirety?
And what entity could help me enforce a request for removal (other than a paid lawyer)?

Comment/Explanation:
The initial couple of answers don't seem to address my concern, so here is another attempt to explain. My question is primarily about the level of protection that PII should get from local governments, not about public records. I do contract work for a federal government agency. I have to undergo training annually for Title-9,13,26 protection of citizen data. It appears to me that local town governments should adhere to the same standards, but I was wondering what the legal basis is.

Comment: It depends on your state.

Comment: @user6726 do tell, in what state is posting an email illegal?

Comment: @Putvi They didn't claim that posting an email is illegal.

Comment: That was meant to be in reference to the comment saying it depends on the state.

Comment: If you are Amazon then you would get two business days to squash FOIA requests:  https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/virginia-politics/open-records-advocate-questions-amazon-arlington-disclosure-clause/2019/03/14/6ebe3124-44fd-11e9-8aab-95b8d80a1e4f_story.html?utm_term=.f5f3cd71f0f4.  I suspect if you are an ordinary peon, you get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is that "public records" must be disclosed unless they are by definition not public records. This study summarizes US public records law on a state by state basis, if the issue is about the US. Taking Massachusetts as an example, the law defines public record [here](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleI/Chapter4/Section7), so if the item is not a public record, it is not required to disclose the item. Clause 26 has a long list of exceptions such as

> (j) the names and addresses of any persons contained in, or referred
>   to in, any applications for any licenses to carry or possess firearms
>   issued pursuant to chapter one hundred and forty or any firearms
>   identification cards issued pursuant to said chapter one hundred and
>   forty and the names and addresses on sales or transfers of any
>   firearms, rifles, shotguns, or machine guns or ammunition therefor, as
>   defined in said chapter one hundred and forty and the names and
>   addresses on said licenses or cards ...
>
> (o) the home address and home
>   telephone number of an employee of the judicial branch, an unelected
>   employee of the general court, an agency, executive office,
>   department, board, commission, bureau, division or authority of the
>   commonwealth, or of a political subdivision thereof or of an authority
>   established by the general court to serve a public purpose, in the
>   custody of a government agency which maintains records identifying
>   persons as falling within those categories; provided that the
>   information may be disclosed to an employee organization under chapter
>   150E, a nonprofit organization for retired public employees under
>   chapter 180, or a criminal justice agency as defined in section 167 of
>   chapter 6.
>
> (p) the name, home address and home telephone number of a family
>   member of a commonwealth employee, contained in a record in the
>   custody of a government agency which maintains records identifying
>   persons as falling within the categories listed in subclause (o).

If the information is not legally a public record, there is no obligation to disclose. There is a general requirement via statute, regulation and court rulings requiring the government to protect personal information, such as [this](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartI/TitleXV/Chapter93h/Section2). You can get a list of sources on that topic [here](https://www.mass.gov/info-details/massachusetts-law-about-privacy#massachusetts-laws-). This does not mean that the government body in question can be forced to redact that information, but it is at least possible that there is a (slim) legal basis for requiring them to protect your privacy.

Comment: Not sure that the commonwealth requirement cited has any provisions that apply to local governments (although those might be located elsewhere in the statutory scheme). It seems limited to state agencies.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can't (successfully) sue the government for money damages for harm caused by the disclosure or for a fine due to sovereign immunity from tort claims except in the case of certain specific exceptions which would almost never included disclosing private information.

You might be able to get injunctive relief (i.e. a court order requiring the town to redact the information), but you would have to establish a duty to maintain privacy first. The duty to protect personal identifying information arises by statute, and mostly it applies only to specific kinds of information (e.g. health information or educational records) and only to certain kinds of entities (usually not town government).

There might be some state law that requires certain information to be kept confidential by town governments, but unless you can find an applicable statute, you will probably not prevail. Since "my name, email address, and in some instances my address and home phone number" are already present in many public records that the public can access (real property records, voter registration records, court filings, applications for various permits), this is almost surely not protected by any statute.

Comment: So basically you are giving him a maybe? This is not an answer.

Comment: Can you site a state law that would make them redact the information? He is in Mass.

Comment: I don't think that one exists for the information he describes.

Answer (score -6):

I'm sorry, but they can put what they want on their site.

If you talked to someone at the town, they would probably remove your address and phone number though.

Comment: I'd disagree - they cannot 'put what they want.' Can they legally put a social security number? Drivers license number? Medical or health information? There are lots of instances of PII that would not be considered legal or "whatever they want." I'd also say that this depends on their state.

Comment: @markb well I'm sorry you disagree lol, but there is no law saying they can't. Theres thousands of websites with that info on them. It's not illegal lol.

Comment: Have you searched for every law in every state? I do believe there are laws restricting 'anything they want'

But I guess since it's a government entity, even if there were laws against it they can do whatever they want because they are a government. If that's your basis then please say so.

Comment: Uhh, my basis is the first amendment.

Comment: @Putvi It would not be unusual for a government agency to be restricted in its disclosure of PII.

Comment: I've done IT work for local governments for many years. There are no laws restricting putting an email on a town's website.

Comment: I'm not trying to be a jerk about it, but just because some people go around saying you can't post this or that does not make it so. Posting or not posting your email to the city in a PDF just has nothing to do with the law. If you don't like it, just ask politely. You don't have to sue everyone, when you can ask nicely.

Comment: You should be clear what you mean in your answer. There, you say "they can put what they want on their site." A couple people disagreed with that and you replied with, "There are no laws restricting putting an email on a town's website." Either change your answer to reflect the latter response, or rebut the disagreements to the answer you actually gave.

Comment: How have I not rebutted it?

Comment: I've told you guys there is no law about posting your email on a website. If, there is one post it or don't expect me to take my time to answer then just say oh theres laws no one can show saying otherwise lol.

Comment: @putvi  - there are laws about things like this in lots of places. I don't agree that 1st Amendment applies to town governments. It applies to people.  Secondly, there is a law in Texas that prevents cities, counties and other taxing authorities from publishing floor plans of houses on their sites. This pretty much refutes your assertion that they can 'put anything there they want.'  Did you catch that in your search? Look at the number of downvotes in your answer.

Comment: What? There is no floor plan law lol. The other answer also says this is not illegal. You people downvote me just for spite.

Comment: @Putvi The 79th Texas Legislature, enacted SB 541, effective September 1, 2005. It provides that appraisal district websites cannot display photographs, sketches, or floor plans of an improvement to real property that is designed primarily for use as a human residence. - Still want to claim "there is no floor plan law lol?"

Comment: @markb link to the actual law if it is so.

Comment: @Putvi - you should be able to look it up yourself - https://law.justia.com/codes/texas/2015/tax-code/title-1/subtitle-d/chapter-25  - scan for the words "floor plan" in Sec. 25.027. RESTRICTION ON POSTING INFORMATION ON INTERNET WEBSITE

Comment: You realize that is data the government collected right? They can make laws about the data they collect, just as they did here.